# Why is Rails query case sensitive in production but not development?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

While I debugging a Rails 5.0.1 app today, I discovered the following unexpected issue.  I have a user in the database who has an email of `Thomas.A.Jones@company.foo`.  When I run

```
User.find_by(email: "thomas.a.jones@company.foo")
```

in production, I get a `nil` back.  However, if I execute

```
User.find_by(email: "Thomas.A.Jones@company.foo")
```

it successfully finds the record.  The weird part, is this doesn't happen when the Rails app is running in development mode.  I can query with `thomas.a.jones@company.foo` or `Thomas.A.Jones@company.foo` and it always finds the record.

What could be causing Rails to make a case sensitive search in production?  The database is Postgres.  All of this is being tested on the same machine with the same code.

**Update 2/10/2017**

Unfortunately, the problem went away after rebuilding my development environment.  After reading some of the comments below, case sensitive searches in production is the expected behavior for Postgres/Rails.  It's still unclear as to why my development environment (on the same machine) was performing case insensitive searches.  I'll update if I find out any more info...

Comment: What's your back-end database? There may be a difference in versions even if exactly the same query is being run, or a schema difference due to server defaults. For example, [with MySQL it depends on collation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case-sensitivity.html). Compare your development table schema to your production schema and look for differences.

Comment: In this particular situation, everything should be the same.  It's the same computer, same backend database (Postgres).  I regenerated the entire DB in development mode by running all the migrations.  Then I recreated the production db by rerunning all the migrations.  But, point taken.  I'll see if I can spot a difference in the final table/schema between the two.

Comment: I'm just making suggestions here, not drawing conclusions. It's highly probable that this is a subtle collation issue. Have you tried `pg_restore` of the working database to see what changed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Postgres is case sensitive by default. You can use [ILIKE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-matching.html) to avoid case sensitivity.

> The key word ILIKE can be used instead of LIKE to make the match case-insensitive according to the active locale. This is not in the SQL standard but is a PostgreSQL extension.

Or change both to lower case then search:

```
User.where("LOWER(email) = ?", email.downcase)
```

Comment: Thank you for the info. I'm hoping to avoid using ILIKE or LOWER.  Hopefully I can track down why the two environments are behaving differently...that scares me.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure, why exactly does it. But there's simple solution.

Put into a model this.

Ex: user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save { self.email = email.downcase }
end
```